# Appropriate approach to provide access to class internal array elements

Tags: c++, arrays, oop, member

I am starting to work on refactoring an already too big and heavily coupled project, in ADAS (automotive) world (so C++ 11 tolerated, but no true dynamic allocation, a common math library mimics some of the stl containers etc...), and I'm facing a recurring issue/interrogation.

What would be considered "best" (or valid/relevant) approach to provide access to a class internal array's element, from index or even from other determining element's field.

For instance, let's say I have an class that makes the interface with outside world from our component (so basically taking some data from other components of the projects, exchanged as pure C structs, with fixed sizes etc for embedded constraints), wrapping it all, providing additional info and access method for our component algos.

If I have an internal array like the following (the vector mimic requires a MAX_SIZE, but behaves like a vector within this outer bound, with a "current size", push_back etc, and most usual accessers)

```
typedef custom_vector_like<element, MAX_ELEMENTS> data_array_type;
class ...
{
    data_array_type m_data;
}
```

What would be considered a valid way to provide a safe "get data at idx" method for the component algo behavior.

Usually I would like to provide const and non-const ref to elements in the array, but how to deal with unexpected idx (out of bound)? Or how to deal with "find element that verifies X condition" if there is no find?

Would you use a reference parameter and return a bool for success (but then user code needs to define a element object to be filled in getter call...)?
Or just assert and let user (dev in debug at worse hopefully?) that he sent non-sense data as input?

Or maybe only provide access to the whole container (const or not) as ref and let user handle looping over / access members?

Comment: You can do like the standard does and overload `operator[]` which returns a reference and is unchecked, have an `at` function that is checked and will throw an exception when out of bounds and then a `find` function the returns an iterator to the found item or the end iterator if no item is found.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thx for the summary, will try to push such good practice within the team :) One more question, how would you unit test the `operator[]` then? is there still an assert or something (I think GoogleTest allows "expect assert" or something)?